# execute_query between two text item in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I need trigger code which show all rows falls between `text_item1` and `text_item2` in **Oracle Forms**.

**For Example:-**

`text_item1=6000` and `text_item2=11000` then 
it show all rows that falls in those items.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a first block (a dummy block) with the 2 items on it.
And then in your second block you can refer to it in the `default-where`.

> tableItem between :block1.item1 and :block1.item2

If it is not necessary that before a query both items always have a value you can also use a `pre-query` trigger instead of the `default-where` and change the default-where clause.